# How can i make file upload with other field like: title, name, image, image2 in Node.js with Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I have a model: Product with title, name,price,color, image, image2 how can i save this in mongoDb?

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
name: String,
price: String,
color: String,
image: {
    type: Buffer
},
```

image2: {
        type: Buffer
    }
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the data using formidable or multer before storing it on mongodb

Personally, I'll recommend formidable.